# Shell command to remove files not working in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a command to remove older files periodically using `crontab`.

The command is :

```
0 * * * * sudo find /path/to/data/ -type f -mmin +600 -name '*.gz' -execdir rm -- '{}' +;
```

This helps me remove all `.gz` files older than 600 mins (10 hours) from the given folder location. It works perfectly in command prompt and in crontab.

Now I modified the above command to delete another group of files. However it works in command prompt but not in crontab.

```
0 * * * * sudo find /path/to/data/ -type f -mmin +600 -name '*.gz%%' -execdir rm -- '{}' +;
```

My files have extension of `*.gz%%`. The file names have been appended by `%%` and can be changed to other character if needed.

The command **runs perfectly fine if ran from command prompt**, yet **when kept in `crontab` does not execute at all.**

Seems like crontab is not able to execute the command. Any pointers to debug or what is the issue in the command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `crontab(5)` man page:

> ```
>    The  "sixth"  field  (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>    run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a  "%"
>    character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the
>    SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the command, unless
>    escaped  with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters,
>    and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as  standard
>    input.
> ```

Comment: Looks like the case.  I cant accept the answer right away. Will do it once it allows me to.